# Add double back slash to single in php

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have searched a lot and tried javascript replace() function and str_replace,addslashes , strip slashes  as well but i am not getting the right output.

This is what im doing:

```
str_replace("\\","\\\\", "C:wamp\www\desi\uploads\artist\bg\9.jpg";
```

THe output i am getting is:

```
C:wampwwwÞsiuploads\A rtist\B g .jpg
```

Then another way i  tried:

```
var clean=  "<?php echo str_replace("\\","@",LINKCONSTANT); ?>".replace("@","\\");
```

Still not working any idea ?

Comment: http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/COhmGa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem isn't solvable by using str_replace like that because the string in double quotes will have the slashes processed by PHP as escape sequences. Using str_replace like this isn't going to solve the problem of PHP (or javascript) handling string escapes - once you have got a backslash into a string it will stay there quite faithfully.

However string constants will work in single quotes as follows:

```
'C:wamp\www\desi\uploads\artist\bg\9.jpg'
```

but as pointed out elsewhere the directory separator in windows is internally handled as either "/" or "\" so just use the "/" (for api calls) and you'll be fine.

If you wish to output a string that is safe to be parsed by javascript then do:

```
echo "var str = ".json_encode('C:wamp\www\desi\uploads\artist\bg\9.jpg').";";
```

which will output in a javascript compatible way:

```
var str = "C:wamp\\www\\desi\\uploads\\artist\\bg\\9.jpg";
```

Comment: i am using actually a constant
define ("ARTIST_BG",getwordking dirfunction);

Comment: what if what iam doing is replacing \ with @ and then in javascript replace it with \\ or something

Comment: @AbdulBasit I meant string constant value using single quotes rather than PHP constant

Comment: well i have resolved the problem by using forward slash instead of backslash  ......and i made another constant with URL so its working now thanks any ways ...

Answer (score 0):

What are you going to achieve? Replace the single `\` by `\\`?

Please note, that

```
  "\\"
```

denotes a string of a single `\`. This is due to the fact, that [`\` prefixes an escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in used inside of `"..."`:

```
  \r  ->  Return
  \t  ->  Tabular
  \n  ->  Newline
```

Since \ has this special meaning, you need to write `\\` to denote a single `\` inside of `"...."`.

Thus, this will set `$resultString` to `C:wamp\\www\\desi\\uploads\\artist\\bg\\9.jpg`:

```
$sourceString = "C:wamp\www\desi\uploads\artist\bg\9.jpg";
$resultString = str_replace( "\\", "\\\\", $sourceString );
```

Comment: i want to replace \ with  \\   and i am using \\ to represent single and \\\\ to represent \\ see my code please

Comment: Isn't that what OP is doing in his first example?

Comment: Yes, it is. I wonder, why his code fails. Thus, I tried to begin at the base level.